# Using a transformer (estimator) to transform the target labels in sklearn.pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn

I understand that one can chain several estimators that implement the transform method to transform X (the feature set) in sklearn.pipeline. However I have a use case where I would like also transform the target labels (like transform the labels to [1...K] instead of [0, K-1] and I would love to do that as a component in my pipeline. Is it possible to that at all using the sklearn.pipeline.?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, pipelines will always pass `y` through unchanged. Do the transformation outside the pipeline.

(This is a known design flaw in scikit-learn, but it's never been pressing enough to change or extend the API.)

Comment: Did this ever get reviewed? This would be very convenient to parallelise aspects of your pipeline where the y in a bounded hyper-parameter also.

Comment: [fred-foo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/fred-foo) I think it makes sense to cite `TransformedTargetRegressor` which was added to the API well after you initially answered this question.

Answer (score 30):

There is now a nicer way to do this built into scikit-learn; using a [`compose.TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#transforming-target-in-regression).

When constructing these objects you give them a `regressor` and a `transformer`. When you `.fit()` them they transform the targets before regressing, and when you `.predict()` them they transform their predicted targets back to the original space.

It's important to note that you can pass them a `pipeline` object, so they should interface nicely with your existing setup. For example, take the following setup where I train a ridge regression to predict 1 target given 2 features:

```py
# Imports
import numpy as np
from sklearn import compose, linear_model, metrics, pipeline, preprocessing

# Generate some training and test features and targets
X_train = np.random.rand(200).reshape(100,2)
y_train = 1.2*X_train[:, 0]+3.4*X_train[:, 1]+5.6
X_test = np.random.rand(20).reshape(10,2)
y_test = 1.2*X_test[:, 0]+3.4*X_test[:, 1]+5.6

# Define my model and scalers
ridge = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=1e-2)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
minmax = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))

# Construct a pipeline using these methods
pipe = pipeline.make_pipeline(scaler, ridge)

# Construct a TransformedTargetRegressor using this pipeline
# ** So far the set-up has been standard **
regr = compose.TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=pipe, transformer=minmax)

# Fit and train the regr like you would a pipeline
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)
print("MAE: {}".format(metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```

This still isn't quite as smooth as I'd like it to be, for example you can access the regressor that contained by a `TransformedTargetRegressor` using `.regressor_` but the coefficients stored there are untransformed. This means there are some extra hoops to jump through if you want to work your way back to the equation that generated the data.

Comment: Do you know a similar functionality for classifiers?

Comment: The python library [`mlinsights`](https://github.com/sdpython/mlinsights), which extends scikit-learn, has added this functionality and called it [`TransformedTargetClassifier2`](https://github.com/sdpython/mlinsights/blob/777bbb85d0203f38aeb6bb5b90c3b87426fbf2db/mlinsights/mlmodel/target_predictors.py#L135).

Comment: Does anyone know how to pass a pandas dataframe through this?

Answer (score 4):

You could add the label column to the end of the training data, then you apply your transformation and you delete that column before training your model. That's not very pro but enough.