# sklearn - Binarize y only as first step in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

**High-level**

1. Convert text data to a count matrix and call it `X`.
2. Convert integer data to binary and call it `y`.
3. Feed data to sklearn `LogisticRegression`

**Primary Question**

How to convert `y` (not `X`, not `X` and `y` together, just `y`) to binary as the FIRST step within an sklearn`Pipeline`.

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['i am a text', 'i am also text', 'turn text into counts',
          'binarize me as text please'], 'Integer': [20, 0, 4, 0]},
          columns=['Text', 'Integer'])
```

**Sample df**

```
                         Text  Integer
0                 i am a text       20
1              i am also text        0
2       turn text into counts        4
3  binarize me as text please        0
```

I know I can do the following with a `Pipeline`:

```
X = df['Text']
y = df['Integer']

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), stop_words='english')),
    ('lr', LogisticRegression()),
    ])
```

Then fit using `X`, `y`:

```
pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

**What I don't Understand**

Since I pass BOTH `X` and `y` to `pipeline.fit(X, y)`, how can I specify within the pipeline to first convert `y` to binary (`0`, `1`) classes?

I realize I can convert `y` before-hand (see below) but the heart of my question is, how to do the preprocessing of `y` within the `Pipeline` using sklearn functions.

```
y = np.where(df['Integer'] >= 1, 1, 0)
```

**Other Notes**

I am aware of and tried `Binarizer` on `y` and it would work for example if I preprocess `y` in the `pipeline.fit` method itself like `pipeline.fit(X, Binarizer().transform(y.reshape((len(y), 1)))[:, 0])` but, again, my intent here is to learn how to preprocess `y` in the `pipeline` (if possible) and not within the `fit` method or before-hand.

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import Binarizer
>>> Binarizer().fit_transform(y)

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 386
    DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 386
    DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
array([[1, 0, 1, 0]])
>>> b = Binarizer()
>>> b.transform(y)

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 386
    DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
array([[1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: It is not possible to preprocess `y` in a traditional scikit-learn pipeline. The problem is `transform` which returns the transformed value only returns a transformed `X`. Maybe someone could suggest an alternative pipeline for scikit-learn, if one exists.

Comment: To point you to a [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602489/using-a-transformer-estimator-to-transform-the-target-labels-in-sklearn-pipeli) that supports Davids comment.  What does `Integer` represent in your example?

Comment: @Kevin That link helps a lot.  FWIW, `Integer` in this example represents the quantity of successes.  I was converting to `0` or `1` because I'm not interested in the quantity but rather if it has ever had a success or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a transformer (estimator) to transform the target labels in sklearn.pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602489/using-a-transformer-estimator-to-transform-the-target-labels-in-sklearn-pipeli)