# Is the score from TransformedTargetRegressor of scikit-learn correct?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, transformer-model

I made a short [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/mGolos/test/blob/master/sklearn_TransformedTargetRegressor.ipynb) to go with my question regarding the TransformedTargetRegressor.
I wanted to put a transformer inside a pipeline to play with a parameter grid but the scores didn't match.

```py
...
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lg_tr = preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(func=np.log, inverse_func=np.exp, check_inverse=True)
y_log = lg_tr.transform(y)
score_0 = model.fit(X, y_log).score(X, y_log)
```

```py
...
model = compose.TransformedTargetRegressor(func=np.log, inverse_func=np.exp, check_inverse=True,
    regressor=linear_model.LinearRegression())
score_1 = model.fit(X, y).score(X, y)
```

The `score_0` value is correct. Why is the one from `score_1` not?
I don't have problem with the prediction that works fine, only the score.
Did I miss something?
Thank you =)

Comment: I think score 1 is the right way to compute the performance in actual target value range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you should be interested on how good your model performs (or scores) when predicting the actual values in their original range or scale. This is however what you are measuring with `score_1` and **not with `score_0`**.

`score_0` represents the model's performance when the target variable is in log scale which is in most cases not very useful.

`score_1` however uses the `score` method of `TransformedTargetRegressor` which makes sure the target variable is in its original scale before computing any performance metric. Thus, judgements should be made based on `score_1`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.
I was too focused on fitting the data and forgot the meaning...
Have a good day =)